# Quantum Rigid Rotor Perturbation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, probability

As the title says, I have a rigid rotor with a perturbation given below
$$H=\frac{L^2}{2I}-\alpha B L_z.$$

So I know that the eigenvalues of $H$ will be $\ell(\ell+1)/2I -\alpha B m$ where $m$ is our projection component.

I am then asked to find the probability that the system will be in the $\ell$th state if it started in the ground state of $H_0$.  This is
$$P=|\int_0^t \langle lm|V|00\rangle e^{i \omega_{fi}t'}dt'|^2$$
Which gives me 0 for the probability that it is in any excited state.  Is this correct?